# Can DMG installer support Scripts?

Tags: ios, macos, packagemaker, dmg, pkg-file

I want to create MAC installer and would like to know which type of installer suitable for my requirements?

My Requirements are

1. I have bash script which does following operation

   - Get Hardware ID and some details specific to the hardware
   - Construct XML
   - Generate PLIST
   - Download an DMG file from internet (Using curl)
   - Mount DMG
   - Launch .app inside the DMG.

Can you please suggest me whether I can go the DMG or use PackageMaker to create .PKG file?

Thanks
Bala

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of anyways to trigger a script on mounting a DMG. But here you have a solution by creating a PKG with pre-install/post install scripts.

Your bash script can be added as pre-install or post-install script of the PKG. It doesn't really matter whether you are adding it as pre/post install scripts, since your PKG is just going to execute the scripts and not doing any file copy etc.

If needed you can embed the PKG in a DMG, so that it becomes a mount disk. Also DMG can show the license files if needed.